# Insert 4 images in a pdf

Tags: linux, bash, pdf-generation, jpeg

I need to print several photos (jpeg), both portrait and landscape, 4 in one page, with a little border/space to separate each image from others in same page and a space for title for each.
I tried with:
    `montage *.jpg -geometry +8+8 -tile 2x2 -quality 90 montage.jpg`

but quality of jpeg was ORRIBLE! Seems '80 game screen!

Comment: Hi, do you mean the printed quality or the quality if you look at the montage.jpg output also?

Comment: The quality if I look at the montage.jpg output.

Comment: hmm sorry can't reproduce but did not manage to get a useful layout of several images on a page using montage anyway ... if you don't mind changing the toolchain, you might use djpeg to make ppms from the pics, align/layout them using gimp and save the result as high quality jpg...